# How do I plot stacked histograms side by side in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I'm looking to plot two side-by-side stacked histograms (similar to the example image below) in matplotlib.
I've tried several variations on

```
bins = np.arange(10)
a1,b1,c1 =plt.hist([arr1,arr2,arr3],bins,stacked=True)
a2,b2,c2 =plt.hist([arr4,arr5,arr6],bins,stacked=True)
```

But can't seem to avoid getting the second plot to directly overlay the first.
Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

[image: Stacked side-by-side histogram example]

Comment: My immediate thought is that the matplotlib barchart demo does exactly this. http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture shows a [bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart) and not a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). I am pointing this out, not only because I am an obnoxious pedant, but also because I believe it could help you find the right tool :-)
Indeed, for your purpose `plt.bar` is probably a better pick than `plt.hist`.

Based on Scironic's suggestion, I modified  this [demonstration example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) to make stacked bars, like the ones on your figure.

Adding an offset to the position index (first argument in `plt.bar()`) is what prevents the bars from overlapping each other.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men1 = (130, 90, 70, 64, 55)
men2 = (120, 85, 62, 50, 53)
men3 = (100, 70, 60, 45, 50)

ind = np.arange(N) + .15 # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men1, width, color='g') 
rects2 = ax.bar(ind, men2, width, color='r') 
rects3 = ax.bar(ind, men3, width, color='b')

women4 = (140, 90, 78, 65, 50)
women5 = (130, 80, 70, 60, 45)
women6 = (120, 60, 60, 55, 44)

xtra_space = 0.05
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width + xtra_space , women1, width, color='orange') 
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width + xtra_space, women2, width, color='cyan') 
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width + xtra_space, women3, width, color='purple')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Population, millions')
ax.set_title('Population: Age Structure')

ax.set_xticks(ind+width+xtra_space)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('USA', 'Brazil', 'Russia', 'Japan', 'Mexico') )

plt.show()
```

[image]